# Server that can save to sql and push to android

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, push

I'm trying to find a way to send an object from android device to a server that will store the object in a database then will push the object to subscribed devices.
I want to use it locally so I don't want to use GCM. Anything but GCM.

My android app saves to mysql via php. The other devies poll the database. I want to use push.

Comment: Please show us your efforts.

Comment: `"to a server" != "use it locally"`

Comment: Well there is a way to upload a sql file to the local network and for devices to fetch that sql file. However, this isn't a "plz give me the codez" site. Show us your effort.

Comment: to a server (local server)

Comment: I have a working app that stores to mysql via php. I need a framework or something like gcm, that can manipulate received objects and send them to subscribers.
I know I can send to server via php,soap,rest. I just don't know how to push to android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To push database to your server, you need to generate an *API* (or for the POC state juste a *.php* file with **POST** argument) and contact it through an **AsyncTask** from your Android code.

To push from the server to the subscribers, I suggest you to take a look at the **Observer design pattern** [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). You'll need to register the app to your server so it can push data to the app back.

Comment: So I have make the client subscribe to server and server push to clients code myself?

Comment: Yes it's want facebook use (kindda) to notify a user on web/phone/tablet platform at the same time.

Comment: There is nothing in mentioned document that describes how a server can push messages to clients.

Comment: A little search will guide you to [Google Cloud  Messaging Service] (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).